# Not exporting correctly images in Polarion

Tags: polarion

I export the workitems to a doc, but the images in the descriptions of the items sometimes are okay, sometimes are not export correctly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGpS7.png)
Other pictures are not in the correct position but they are displayed correctly

I try with different templates, but it did not work